# How to handle build API version > minSdkVersion?

Tags: android

my app has minSdkVersion = 8, targetSdkVersion = 15 and SDK build version = 8. In general it works well, including on ICS but I would like to provide few more features to ICS users, for example resizeable widgets. This requires increasing also the SDK build version to 15.

I am concerned about the API static safety. For example if I will use unintentionally an API features that is not available on old phones.

What are good practices to handle SDK build version > minSdkVersion? How can I verify before shipping a new version that it does not break on old phones? What are good practices to address it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is considered "good practise", but I just open the file `project.properties` and change the property `target=android-11` to whatever API level I want to check. Once the file is saved, Eclipse will starting flagging errors where the API calls above the set version are. I just scan through them, check that they're encompassed by API-level checks, and then change the property back.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. Anybody has other tricks in their sleeves?

Answer (score 0):

I tried Glitch's answer (thanks!), it kind of works but not as I expected. My widget info files have API 15 attributes such as

```
android:minResizeWidth="40dp"
android:minResizeHeight="40dp"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
```

When I change the SDK build version from 15 to 8, these lines are flagged at error (which is fine) which fail the generation of the R class. This in turn flags every reference to R as an error (hundrads). Now, if I have something like

```
someApi15SpecificMethod(R.xyz)
```

Since the argument is undefined, it cannot tell safely if someApi15SpecificMethod(...) exists in API 8.

Since Glitch's answer is the best so far I am flagging it at the answer but please keep posting ideas here.